# CSS: remove edge / ie animations

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Not so surprisingly scale effects look horrible in ms edge browsers. Is there a way to disable this all together for edge?

```
.jumbotron__bg {
 -webkit-animation-name: animateBg;
 animation-name: animateBg;
 -ms-animation-name: none;

 animation-duration: 18000ms;
 animation-fill-mode: both;

 animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.3,0,.7,1);
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


@keyframes animateBg {
  from {
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
 }

 to {
 transform: scale(1, 1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
 }
}
```

(ie is ok, does not work for edge)

Comment: I changed the tags on your questions, jQuery and linear gradients were not relevant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `@supports` with a property that only Edge supports ;

this works on Edge 12 and later (all versions) :

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
     .jumbotron__bg {
         animation-name: none;
     }
}
```

~or~

this only works in Edge up to v13

```
@supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
     .jumbotron__bg {
         animation-name: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: While `-ms-ime-align: auto` works, `-ms-accelerator:true` does not work for me

Comment: @conceptdeluxe this is probably due to Edge 14 and later dropping support for it. i'll update the answer.